# AEM-curl script to check the status of the bundle

Tags: curl, aem

We have a requirement to write a wrapper shell script which is intended to install the bundles, start the installed bundles. We have written the cURL scripts to install the bundles.Can anyone please help me cURL command to check the status of the bundle.

Regards,
Swathi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/<bundleSymbolicName>.json
```

check for response.data.state

bundle id can also be used instead of Symbolic Name.